# Python - how to listen for UDP data on public ip and port?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ip, portforwarding

I have a UDP socket to receive some data.

```
import socket
import struct

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(('', 8321))

print("Listening")

while True:
    message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
```

However, I would like to receive data externally, outside my local network.

Is there a way to do this?

I imagine this would be possible *without* port forwarding. Am I correct?

<strike>Isn't there something related to MAC addresses involved?</strike> Edit: nevermind, this is only for NAT.

It doesn't matter if a random public port is chosen each time I start the app, as long as I can communicate with it.

Comment: You need to configure port forwarding on your router.

Comment: MAC addresses are only used within a single LAN, not on the public Internet.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a network configuration issue.

Comment: @Barmar But how does Google send data back to me if I go to google.com without port forwarding? Yeah, you're probably right, not really a programming question.

Comment: Port forwarding is for servers, not clients.

Comment: @Barmar But imagine I am a UDP socket (let's call it a client), and I send data to google and want to listen for data that comes back. As you said port forwarding is not for clients. So my question is how to achieve this?

Comment: That's done by NAT. When an outgoing request is sent, the router remembers the source port it assigned, and it forwards replies back to the original sender.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, but how do I actually create such a socket like that where it can be reached from the outside?

Comment: Bind the socket and use `socket.sendto()` to send the request. Then listen for the reply.

Comment: @Barmar Is it that simple? Will that make a publicly-accessible port that gets handled with the NAT?

Comment: No. It only forwards the replies from the address you sent to. And it's temporary.

Comment: If you want a public server, you have to use port forwarding.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean by temporary? I understand that if the client is re-created it will have a different arbitrary port. But if the client remains, will the same port remain open?

Comment: There's no way for the router to know whether the socket is still open. All it sees are the packets that are sent and received.

Comment: Since UDP is normally used for short-term request/response protocols, it discards the NAT entry after a few minutes.

Comment: @Barmar Ok thanks for that information!